# Elastic search with GUID ID without attributes

Tags: c#, nest, elasticsearch-net

We are looking to switch from a relational database to elastic search and I am trying to get some basic code up and running with Nest. We have existing objects which use guids for ids that I would like to save into an elastic search index.

I don't want to add any specific attributes as the class is used in different applications and I don't want to add unnecessary dependencies to Nest.

Right now my code looks like this:

```
var node = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(node) 
settings.DefaultIndex = "test";
var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

var testItem = new TestType { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Test", Value = "10" };

var response = client.Index(testItem);
```

With TestType as:

```
public class TestType
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}
```

However I get an error like:

> ServerError: 400Type: mapper_parsing_exception Reason: "failed to
>   parse [id]" CausedBy: "Type: number_format_exception Reason: "For
>   input string: "c9c0ed42-86cd-4a94-bc86-a6112f4c9188""

I think I need to specify a mapping that tells the server the Id is a string, but I can't find any examples or documentation on how I do this without using the attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using Elasticsearch 2.x and NEST 2.x (e.g. latest of both at time of writing is Elasticsearch 2.3.5 and NEST 2.4.3), then [NEST will automatically infer the id of a POCO by default from the `Id` property](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/ids-inference.html). In the case of a GUID id, this will be saved as a string in Elasticsearch.

Here's an example to get you going

```
void Main()
{
    var node = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(node)
        // default index to use if one is not specified on the request
        // or is not set up to be inferred from the POCO type
        .DefaultIndex("tests");

    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

    // create the index, and explicitly provide a mapping for TestType
    client.CreateIndex("tests", c => c
        .Mappings(m => m
            .Map<TestType>(t => t
                .AutoMap()
                .Properties(p => p
                    // don't analyze ids when indexing,
                    // so they are indexed verbatim
                    .String(s => s
                        .Name(n => n.Id)
                        .NotAnalyzed()
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );

    var testItem = new TestType { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Test", Value = "10" };

    // now index our TestType instance
    var response = client.Index(testItem);
}

public class TestType
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}
```

[Take a look at the Automapping documentation for more examples](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/auto-map.html) of how to explicitly map a POCO for controlling [norms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/norms.html), [analyzers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html), [multi_fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/mapping-types.html#_multi_fields_2), etc.

Comment: That fixed it, thanks. I had found that documentation but I don't think its very good, probably OK as a reference but for someone just starting with the API not easy to follow at all.

Comment: @Mant101 feel free to ask questions on here or https://discuss.elastic.co/c/elasticsearch. Pull Requests for documentation also most welcome ;)

Answer (score 1):

What I normally do is to have a separate class that is only specific to Elasticsearch. And use Automapper to map that into a DTO or ViewModel, or Model into the Elasticsearch Document.

That way, you won't have to expose an object that have a dependency in NEST and attributes that might be specific only to Elasticsearch.

Another good reason is that normally, documents in ES are flat, so you would normally flatten your objects before you index them to ES.

Comment: These types are already flat as they are saved in a relational DB, that is their primary function. They are also used in a website in places where it isn't worth having a view model. There are also a lot of them and I don't want to duplicate them all.

Comment: Understood, it seems that from the error message. NEST was able to infer the id field, but wasn't able to infer the type Guid.