# Guid ID comparison with NEST using Xamarin.Forms not working

Tags: elasticsearch, xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform, nest

I'm developing an app for iOS and Android with *Xamarin 6.1* and I'm using *Xamarin.Forms 2.3.1* 
The app scans a QR using *ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms 2.1.4* that contains a Guid Id and saves it as a string into my ElasticSearch. To connect with ElasticSearch I'm using NEST 2.x

The problem is that when I scan the same QR again (when I know for sure that it is already indexed) it is detected as a new one even tho the values are the same (both compared as strings). However I tried to remove the dashes ( - ) from the id before storing or comparing them and it works.

This is my model:

```
public class Box
{
    [String(Analyzer = "null")]
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string lastUpdate { get; set; }
}
```

**result.Text** is what I get from the QR and I know for sure that is a string, and this is how I index it:

```
scannedQR = result.Text;

// INDEXING
var timeStamp = GetTimestamp(DateTime.Now);
var customBox = new Box {
                          id= scannedQR, 
                          lastUpdate = timeStamp 
                        };
var res = client.Index(customBox, p => p
                        .Index("airstorage")
                        .Type("boxes")
                        .Id(scannedQR)
                        .Refresh()
                      );
```

And this is how I check if the QR already exists:

```
var resSearch = client.Search<Box>(s => s
                                    .Index("airstorage")
                                    .Type("boxes")
                                    .From(0)
                                    .Size(10)
                                    .Query(q => q
                                           .Term(p => p.id, scannedQR)
                                        )
                                    );

if (resSearch.Documents.Count() > 0) {
    Console.WriteLine("EXISTING");
}
else { 
    Console.WriteLine("NEW BOX");
}
```

I have also tried to set the property to .NotAnalyse to the index in ElasticSearch when creating it like suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38744531/elastic-search-with-guid-id-without-attributes) but still doesn't work.

Anyone any idea? Everything is welcome!

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would set the `id` field on your `Box` POCO to not analyzed

```
public class Box
{
    [String(Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)]
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string lastUpdate { get; set; }
}
```

The `id` property will still be indexed but will not undergo analysis, so will be indexed verbatim.

I would also check for the existence of the document using

```
var existsResponse = client.DocumentExists<Box>("document-id", e => e.Index("airstorage").Type("boxes"));

if (!existsResponse.Exists)
{
    Console.WriteLine("document exists")
}
```

***BUT***, actually what I think you want is to [use optimistic concurrency control](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/optimistic-concurrency-control.html) for the creation document in the index call i.e. if the document doesn't exist then index it, but if it does exist then return a 409 Conflict invalid response. The `OpType.Create` can be used for this

```
var indexResponse = client.Index(box, i => i
    .OpType(OpType.Create)
    .Index("airstorage")
    .Type("boxes"));

if (!indexResponse.IsValid)
{
    if (indexResponse.ApiCall.HttpStatusCode == 409)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("document exists");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"error indexing document: {indexResponse.DebugInformation}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @RussCam! I added the POCO to the `id` declaration and the `.OpType(OpType.Create)` and now it works!

Comment: can you maybe help me out here? ^^' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39931708/how-to-store-a-c-sharp-list-of-objects-into-elasticsearch-with-nest-2-x/39932064#39932064